# What is wrong with my merge sort visualization?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, algorithm, recursion, mergesort

I am trying to create a merge sort visualizer.

The merge sort works in the sense that if I give it an array, it'll spit back a correctly sorted array. The problem is that the "visualization" aspect of my program isn't quite working as I thought it would.

The way I attempted the implementation was that `mergeSort()` would take the two elements being compared, <s>highlight them in red</s> (no longer focusing on this for now to simplify problem), then swap the height if necessary, <s>then turn the two elements back to the default colour</s>:

```js
const {
  useState,
  useEffect
} = React;

const numberOfBars = 8; //Number of bars shown on screen
const animationSpeed = 100; //How fast the bars animate

function SortingVisualizer() {
  const [arr, setArr] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    newArray();
  }, [])

  function newArray() {
    const tempArr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < numberOfBars; i++) {
      tempArr.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 5)
    }
    setArr(tempArr);
  }

  return ( 
    <div id = "main-container" >

    <button id = "new-array-button" onClick = {() => newArray()}> New Array </button>  
    <button id = "merge-sort-button" onClick = {() => mergeSort(arr)}> Merge Sort < /button> 

    <div id = "bar-container" >

    {
      arr.map((value, index) => ( 
        <div className = 'bar'
        key = {
          index
        }
        style = {
          {
            backgroundColor: "aquamarine",
            height: value + "px"
          }
        }
        />
      ))
    }

    </div>  
    </div >
  )
}

// Recursively breaks down unsortedArray into lowIndex, midIndex, highIndex and pass to mergeSortHelper()
// Initialized aux, lowIndex and highIndex in argument.
function mergeSort(unsortedArray, aux = [...unsortedArray], lowIndex = 0, highIndex = unsortedArray.length - 1) {
  // Base case
  if (highIndex === lowIndex) return;

  // Get midIndex
  const midIndex = Math.floor((highIndex + lowIndex) / 2);

  // Recursively run left side and right side until base case reached.
  mergeSort(unsortedArray, aux, lowIndex, midIndex);
  mergeSort(unsortedArray, aux, midIndex + 1, highIndex);

  // Merge the left sides and right sides
  mergeSortHelper(unsortedArray, aux, lowIndex, midIndex, highIndex);
}



// Does the work of sorting list and animating the height swap
function mergeSortHelper(unsortedArray, aux, lowIndex, midIndex, highIndex) {
  let auxkey = lowIndex;
  let i = lowIndex;
  let j = midIndex + 1;
  let barI = undefined;
  let barJ = undefined;

  // While there are elements in left/right sides, put element in auxillary array
  // then increment the indexes by 1.
  while (i <= midIndex && j <= highIndex) {
    let arrayBars = document.getElementsByClassName('bar');
    barI = arrayBars[i].style;
    barJ = arrayBars[j].style;

    if (unsortedArray[i] <= unsortedArray[j]) {
      aux[auxkey] = unsortedArray[i];
      auxkey++;
      i++;
    } else {
      let tmpHeight = barJ.height; //swaps value at index i and j
      barJ.height = barI.height;   //swaps value at index i and j
      barI.height = tmpHeight;     //swaps value at index i and j

      aux[auxkey] = unsortedArray[j];
      auxkey++;
      j++;
    }
  }

  // Move any remaining elements from unsortedArray into auxillary array.
  while (i <= midIndex) {
    aux[auxkey] = unsortedArray[i];
    auxkey++;
    i++;
  }

  // Copy the auxillary array to the unsortedArray so that in the next iteration, the unsortedArray will reflect the new array
  for (let k = 0; k <= highIndex; k++) {
    unsortedArray[k] = aux[k];
  }
}


ReactDOM.render( < SortingVisualizer / > , document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```css
#new-array-button {
  position: absolute;
}

#merge-sort-button {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
}

#bar-container {
  align-items: flex-end;
  background-color: lightgray;
  display: flex;
  height: 200px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.bar {
  margin: 0 2px;
  width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

I've been trying to implement the color change and height swap in different parts of my program but it never seems to work correctly. Where am I going wrong with the visualization?

*Removed my jsfiddle link from the question as I am using the on-site code snippet now. But in case anyone still wants it, it's here: https://jsfiddle.net/SushiCode/k0954yep/17/*

Comment: It is good that you present only relevant code, but your code has undefined variables. It should be minimal, but it should also be self-contained.

Comment: @trincot, ah thanks. For undefined variables, do you mean like explain what auxkey does, what aux is, barJ, etc?

Comment: That would be good, but also you could initialise those variables in your code snippet with useful values. That way we could actually run the code and see your problem. Again, it should not be your full-blown code... just enough to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Did you mean to do `setTimeout` with a delay of one-tenth of a *millisecond*?

Comment: @ScottSauyet yeah that was intentional but I've changed it now to be a variable called animationSpeed so people can adjust how fast or slow the animation is.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstrating the problem, ideally a runnable one using Stack Snippets. ([Here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/).)

Comment: I made some changes. This is the first time I've heard of code snippet and "minimal, complete, and verifiable" so let me know if more edits are needed @ScottSauyet

Comment: @SushiCode: That is definitely an improvement.  I'm headed to bed now, but if I can make some time tomorrow, I'll try to look at it.